# Calculate date difference of dataframe groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I need to calculate the length of time (in years) between dates of groups. For example, I want the difference between the *first* time a `Name`-`ID` group appeared (identified by `%_chng=New`), and the date in the `Date` column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'Faye', 1: 'Faye', 2: 'Faye', 3: 'Faye', 4: 'Faye', 5: 'Faye', 6: 'Faye', 7: 'Mike', 8: 'Mike', 9: 'Mike', 10: 'Mike', 11: 'Mike', 12: 'Mike', 13: 'Mike', 14: 'Mike'}, 'Date': {0: '2020-12-31', 1: '2020-09-30', 2: '2020-06-30', 3: '2018-09-30', 4: '2018-09-30', 5: '2018-09-30', 6: '2018-06-30', 7: '2020-12-31', 8: '2020-09-30', 9: '2020-09-30', 10: '2020-06-30', 11: '2020-03-30', 12: '2019-12-31', 13: '2019-09-30', 14: '2019-06-30'}, 'ID': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'A', 8: 'A', 9: 'C', 10: 'C', 11: 'C', 12: 'C', 13: 'C', 14: 'C'}, '%_chng': {0: '0.3', 1: '0.2', 2: 'New', 3: '0.1', 4: 'New', 5: '0.2', 6: 'New', 7: '0.7', 8: 'New', 9: '0.1', 10: '0.2', 11: '0.1', 12: '0.4', 13: '0.3', 14: 'New'}})

    Name        Date ID %_chng
0   Faye  2020-12-31  A    0.3
1   Faye  2020-09-30  A    0.2
2   Faye  2020-06-30  A    New
3   Faye  2018-09-30  A    0.1
4   Faye  2018-09-30  A    New
5   Faye  2018-09-30  B    0.2
6   Faye  2018-06-30  B    New
7   Mike  2020-12-31  A    0.7
8   Mike  2020-09-30  A    New
9   Mike  2020-09-30  C    0.1
10  Mike  2020-06-30  C    0.2
11  Mike  2020-03-30  C    0.1
12  Mike  2019-12-31  C    0.4
13  Mike  2019-09-30  C    0.3
14  Mike  2019-06-30  C    New
```

So the expected output would look something like:

```
    Name        Date ID %_chng  date_length
0   Faye  2020-12-31  A    0.3         0.50
1   Faye  2020-09-30  A    0.2         0.25
2   Faye  2020-06-30  A    New         0.00
3   Faye  2018-09-30  A    0.1         0.25
4   Faye  2018-09-30  A    New         0.00
5   Faye  2018-09-30  B    0.2         0.25
6   Faye  2018-06-30  B    New         0.00
7   Mike  2020-12-31  A    0.7         0.25
8   Mike  2020-09-30  A    New         0.00
9   Mike  2020-09-30  C    0.1         1.25
10  Mike  2020-06-30  C    0.2         1.00
11  Mike  2020-03-30  C    0.1         0.75
12  Mike  2019-12-31  C    0.4         0.50
13  Mike  2019-09-30  C    0.3         0.25
14  Mike  2019-06-30  C    New         0.00
```

Comment: could you add an example for how you calculate the date length for one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `cumsum` create the additional `groupby` key then do `transform`

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
s = df['%_chng'].eq('New').iloc[::-1].cumsum()
datediff = df.groupby([df['Name'],df['ID'],s])['Date'].transform('last')
df['date_length'] = (df['Date'] - datediff).dt.days//90/4

    Name       Date ID %_chng  date_length
0   Faye 2020-12-31  A    0.3         0.50
1   Faye 2020-09-30  A    0.2         0.25
2   Faye 2020-06-30  A    New         0.00
3   Faye 2018-09-30  A    0.1         0.00
4   Faye 2018-09-30  A    New         0.00
5   Faye 2018-09-30  B    0.2         0.25
6   Faye 2018-06-30  B    New         0.00
7   Mike 2020-12-31  A    0.7         0.25
8   Mike 2020-09-30  A    New         0.00
9   Mike 2020-09-30  C    0.1         1.25
10  Mike 2020-06-30  C    0.2         1.00
11  Mike 2020-03-30  C    0.1         0.75
12  Mike 2019-12-31  C    0.4         0.50
13  Mike 2019-09-30  C    0.3         0.25
14  Mike 2019-06-30  C    New         0.00
```